# How to extract sessionKey from below response in Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

How to extract sessionKey from the below response using Jmeter?

`<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://hpc.uat.freedompay.com/api/v1.2/controls?sessionKey=eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2R0NNS1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwiaXYiOiJ3QWRBa0pYZHRFZjRJZ0FyIiwidGFnIjoiYnkza094VWcteTNMSVdGZXpwRXVZZyIsInppcCI6IkRFRiJ9.UyZuzOJjUUH_W4Y8562QQEE3sMInJBC5nbBw_iROmlT307ij_HpVTHIkkTGOYtjJ3fqqj98xrg6mmFQAYUvCMw.BK539lfAMdXR1W08rDGSew.W8fNSXnjy85FFMVBunjYJ81pTwhDxoNLfBAyh4xsr2442LYTxu_C8r4BsYrASO6cq1cN73K7IAOz-77fc17Vw49eb61wo8urEacXUcT8i8jy7fq4TrTqFq3YLgjiE-1Q8ytn9T9hKSrPIOABFhy69th4SpvHKTJ6qVSz1ZmQ6Df3jKVmL4CUXrqqLrSRuDg-0jFChqIjSROI8q-ZBfBoZxUZ6GWsek4GiLa21nWZHHeIB2yAMAX1c4oTQJr3kcKcslIlIKtRHGQYF2V9lDrnZflViY6a1ZzzAoNAK9avjEn3tK-mFLiBRzTxastq-TbfnFao5b1UVhVVx4woCIwgKw-WYl69x91dO6oPHexUTnfrd5J86zqQGZXzAwuA7E1tt1WJSz720mRfSFwduuF_8uisTHYPuAXC36y9n1fgQ3C0S6gbeVj9Hm1LpUuRgX81tYVIRb8EpZEaAcizp1TbEA.kZogTE6vDXDhIEO2joVCRC6FY3URy4aWcIqB7E2i4_k"></iframe>`

Comment: Most of what you want can be found at https://zuhaibahmed.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/how-to-extract-value-from-html-response-and-use-it-in-another-request-in-jmeter/ Please attempt to use the information, then update your question with what you tried and the results you received. That will make the question eligible for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

That is a `html` response. You will need to add an `extractor` to parse the HTML and extract the data. Using Jmeter right click on the thread group and select post processors, then `CSS selector extractor`. Once added define the variable name as `var1`, set the `CSS selector expression` to `iframe`, set the `attribute` to `sessionKey`, set match number to 1 and tick box for empty variable if nothing is found, like this:

[image]

Bare in mind that Jmeter offers a wide variaty of extractors (xpath, json, regular expression and so on), you can also use xpath or regexp here if that is what you prefer.